# Generate new unique IDs for dynamically created content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have built an invoice application, which adds rows dynamically.

This is the code that generates rows:

```
$("#addrow").click(function(){
    $(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td><div class="inp"><input type="file" class="fileUpload"/><img id="myImg" src="#" alt="your image" /></div></td><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea></textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td class="description"><textarea></textarea></td><td><textarea class="cost">$</textarea></td><td><textarea class="qty"></textarea></td><td><span class="price">$0</span></td></tr>');
    if ($(".delete").length > 0) $(".delete").show();
    bind();
});
```

This is the code of input button that displays the image:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(":file").change(function () {
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            }
        });
    });

    function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
    };
</script>
```

So as you see the problem is with image ids and buttons, how can I generate ids for each image and button in the new rows?

Comment: Use `.length` of `.item-row` collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as the image is just after the button, just select it that way and forget about the id.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#items").on('change', ':file', function () {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var $button = $(this);
            reader.onload = function(e) {
              $button.next().attr('src', e.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="items"><tr class="item-row"><td><div class="inp"><input type="file" class="fileUpload"/><img id="myImg" src="#" alt="your image" /></div></td><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea></textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td class="description"><textarea></textarea></td><td><textarea class="cost">$</textarea></td><td><textarea class="qty"></textarea></td><td><span class="price">$0</span></td></tr><tr class="item-row"><td><div class="inp"><input type="file" class="fileUpload"/><img id="myImg" src="#" alt="your image" /></div></td><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea></textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td class="description"><textarea></textarea></td><td><textarea class="cost">$</textarea></td><td><textarea class="qty"></textarea></td><td><span class="price">$0</span></td></tr><tr class="item-row"><td><div class="inp"><input type="file" class="fileUpload"/><img id="myImg" src="#" alt="your image" /></div></td><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea></textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td class="description"><textarea></textarea></td><td><textarea class="cost">$</textarea></td><td><textarea class="qty"></textarea></td><td><span class="price">$0</span></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Your issue here is that the dynamic rows doesn't exist when you bind the handler. This is solved with event delegation, see updated answer.

Comment: Man !!! You just made my day , thanks for this brilliant help ... if you need anything just ask ! thanks again